# Hiding a variable

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, variables

I have a JavaScript to do list which has 3 variables which are the 3 columns within the table in e database that the information is being pulled from. The 3 are id, content and status, when displaying the data in a list it displays the content along with the status which is just a number, the number determines what colour the content will be which I have done using CSS, however I don't want the number displayed after the content, any way of hiding this?

Heres some of the php code which is pulling it in:

```
public function getList()
    {   
        $link = $this->connect();
        // Query for all the entries from the table and order them based on the id descendingly
        $query = "SELECT * FROM tbToDoList ORDER BY STATUS";

        $res = mysql_query($query);

        $res_array = array();
        // fetch all the entires one by one
        while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){
            // put query result in php array
            $array = array('id' => $row['id'],
                           'content' => $row['content'],
                           'status'=> $row['status']);
```

And here is some of the JS
// Render to-do list view

```
todo.getView = function (res){
    // if the list has more than two entries, grants the permission to use massive weapon/delete all
    if(res.length >= 2){
        $('#massiveWeapon').css('display', 'block');
    }
    // update the list view
    for (var i=0; i< res.length; i++){
$("<li/>", {"id": res[i].id, "text": res[i].content + res[i].status, "class": 'status-' + res[i].status}).appendTo(todo.list);      if(res[i].content.length >= 35){
            $('#'+res[i].id).css("height","50px");
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: This is PHP, not JS: the only JS is your function declaration.

Comment: forgot to add in some of the js code, the PHP code is pulling in the info

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your javascript definition of the item, you are setting the text to `res[i].content + res[i].status`. If you don't want the status in the text, remove the `+ res[i].status` from the text.